# how to avoid nodejs Parse Error when http.get xlsx files?

Tags: node.js, excel

I am downloading xlsx file

```
var options = urlObj;
options.method = 'GET';
options.headers = {'Content-Type':'text/plain'};
function reqCallback(res) {
    // default: 'utf8'
    res.setEncoding('utf8'); //utf16le'); //binary'); //hex'); //utf8
    res.pipe (
        simplexlsx( function (err, table) {
                        if (err) {console.log('simple-xlsx: '+err)};
                        console.log('simplexlsx for '+ table);
                    })
    )
}
var req = http.request(options);
req.on('response', reqCallback); 
req.end();
```

from:

```
server: 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5'
'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET'
```

which I don't own also in the header:

```
'content-type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

and getting:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1588:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
```

I pipe the response to simple-xlsx parser to json, which works fine when the error is handled.

When I set: setEncoding('hex')

```
simple-xlsx: Error: invalid signature: 0x62343035
```

or setEncoding('binary')

```
simple-xlsx: Error: invalid distance too far back
```

and setEncoding('utf16le') or setEncoding('utf8') getting the parse error.

How to work around the parse error?

Comment: You need to add a bit more code, at least the `reqCallback` function, it's almost impossible to tell what's happening otherwise.

Comment: More code..... Can not answer without knowing more...

Comment: function reqCallback(res) { 
     res.pipe (simplexlsx( function (err, table) {
            if (err) {console.log('simple-xlsx: '+err)};
            console.log('simplexlsx for '+ table);

            }))
   }

Comment: Given it's `simplexlsx` that's throwing the error, it would be worth posting that code (if it's yours). If it's an NPM package then a link to the source would help.

Comment: the error pops out even when not using simplexlsx and it shows where

Comment: nothing special:
function reqCallback(res) { 
    res.setEncoding('hex'); //utf16le'); //binary'); //hex'); //utf8
    res.pipe (
     simplexlsx( function (err, table) {
                      if (err) {console.log('simple-xlsx: '+err)};
                      console.log('simplexlsx for '+ table);
           })
    )
}

Comment: sorry can not format it any better new here

Comment: the error pops out even when not using simple-xlsx and it shows where it is not caught by the simple-xlsx. it happens before.

Comment: Well you're not catching errors on the `req` nor the `res`. I.e. `req.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err); });`